# SQL xml merge first row values with rest of the rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I would like to know in SQL Server how do I take the following XML and represent the following table.

```
<Family>
  <Main Surname="Smith" />
  <Person Name="Fred" />
  <Person Name="Jane" />
</Family>

Row Name    Surname
1   Fred    Smith
2   Jane    Smith
```

Please note I cannot change the XML schema.

Here is my current SQL query.

```
declare @Input XML
set @Input = '<Family> <Main Surname="Smith" /> <Person Name="Fred" /> <Person Name="Jane" /> </Family>'

    SELECT 
    Test.value('(@Name)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Name,
    Test.value('(@Surname)[1]', 'varchar(20)') as Surname
    FROM @Input.nodes('/Family/*') AS Tbl(Test) 
OPTION ( OPTIMIZE FOR ( @Input = NULL ) )
```

Comment: Why is this tagged with R?

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @xml XML = '
<Family>
  <Main Surname="Smith" />
  <Person Name="Fred" />
  <Person Name="Jane" />
</Family>'

SELECT
      RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 1/0)
    , t.c.value('@Name', 'VARCHAR(20)')
    , t2.c2.value('@Surname', 'VARCHAR(20)')
FROM @xml.nodes('Family/Person') t(c)
CROSS APPLY t.c.nodes('../Main') t2(c2)
```

results -

```
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                    Fred                 Smith
2                    Jane                 Smith
```

Comment: Hi @BuddyLove, as this is your first question on SO please allow me one hint: It is kind of you to say thank you, but it would be even better to tick the answer as accepted (and - after having got 15 reputation points yourself - vote it up). This will show to other users (e.g. me), that this question is solved and it will give some points to Devart. That's the best way to say thank you on SO. Happy coding!